# Aggregate data not in Particular Time Slot

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection, which store date of births of children with time in mongodb database. User can create a slot and based on that user can children details born in that particular time slot. for example for today user selects, 08:00 AM - 09:30 AM, user can see the details on the screen, which I'm able to accomplish successfully.

I'm not able to fetch details of the children who don't fall in any time slot. For example user created 4 slots [08:00 AM - 09:30 AM, 11:00 AM - 12:00, 2:30 PM - 6:30 PM, 09:00 PM - 09:30 PM] , I want fetch the details of the children who don't fall in any of the four time slot.

First, i will retrieve the slots present in slot collection, then iterate the each slot from nodejs API and send it to below code and retrieve the details.

```
[
{ $match : {'BornTime': {$gte: start, $lte: end} } },
{ $project:{
"_id": 0,
"name":{$concat: [
        {$cond:[{ $eq: ['status', 1] }, "Children Born", ""]},
        {$cond:[{ $eq: ['status', 0] }, "Children Died", ""]},      
        ]},
    "childcount":'childcount'}},

{ $group: { _id: '$name', count: { $sum: 1 } , covers: { $sum: '$childcount' } } },
]
```

Please help me in retrieving the details which don't fall into any slots. I couldn't post that part because i couldn't get it right or i don't have any idea how to implement it, i tried using $not, but couldn't succeed.

Please let me know if more clarification is needed on any of the above details.

Comment: Work out which times fall "outside" the slots and query to match "those" times, which should be pretty simple. Not really sure what you are asking here. Do you want get all all "births/deaths" in a day and then just identify in a "slot"? If so then your iteration here seems a bit redundant.

Comment: I did that, but thought, it increasing the iterations. Is there any way, i can do this through array implementation.

Comment: Actually I think everything can just be one query. With a little creative building of the aggregation identifiers then you can simply categorize each slot and the "noSlot" in one simple pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your process here can be streamlined and also get you the results you want all at once without needing to "iterate" as you say you are doing

Let's say we use the four slots as mentioned in the question, and we are looking for the results for today. The I would do this which will categorize the results all in one hit:

```js
var today = new Date("2015-08-11T00:00:00.000Z"),
    tomorrow = new Date("2015-08-12T00:00.000Z"),
    slots = [
      [new Date("2015-08-11T08:00:00.000Z"),new Date("2015-08-11T09:30:00.000Z")],
      [new Date("2015-08-11T11:00:00.000Z"),new Date("2015-08-11T12:00:00.000Z")],
      [new Date("2015-08-11T14:30:00.000Z"),new Date("2015-08-11T18:30:00.000Z")],
      [new Date("2015-08-11T21:00:00.000Z"),new Date("2015-08-11T21:30:00.000Z")]
    ];


var stack = [];

for (var i = slots.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var rec = {
    "$cond": [
      { "$and": [
        { "$gte": [ "$BornTime", slots[i][0] ]},
        { "$lte": [ "$BornTime", slots[i][1] ]}
      ]},
      i
    ]
  };

  if ( stack.length == 0 ) {
    rec["$cond"].push("noSlot");
  } else {
    var lval = stack.pop();
    rec["$cond"].push(lval);
  }

  stack.push(rec);

}

var pipeline = [
    // Match today
    { "$match":{ "BornTime": { "$gte": today, "$lt": tomorrow } } },

    // Group 
    { "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "name": { 
          "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$status", 1 ] },
            { "$literal": "ChildrenBorn" },
            { "$literal": "ChildrenDied" }
          ]
        },
        "slot": stack[0]
      },
      "count": { "$sum": 1 },
      "covers": { "$sum": "$childcount" }
    }}
];
```

That actually build up the "slot" entry for the grouping in the pipeline stage like this:

```js
{
  "$cond" : [
    {
      "$and" : [
        {
          "$gte" : [
            "$BornTime",
            ISODate("2015-08-11T08:00:00Z")
          ]
        },
        {
          "$lte" : [
            "$BornTime",
            ISODate("2015-08-11T09:30:00Z")
        ]}
      ]
    },
    0,
    {
      "$cond" : [
      {
        "$and" : [
          {
            "$gte" : [
              "$BornTime",
              ISODate("2015-08-11T11:00:00Z")
            ]
          },
          {
            "$lte" : [
              "$BornTime",
              ISODate("2015-08-11T12:00:00Z")
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      1,
      {
        "$cond" : [
          {
            "$and" : [
              {
                 "$gte" : [
                   "$BornTime",
                   ISODate("2015-08-11T14:30:00Z")
                 ]
              },
              {
               "$lte" : [
                 "$BornTime",
                 ISODate("2015-08-11T18:30:00Z")
               ]
              }
            ]
          },
          2,
          {
            "$cond" : [
              {
                 "$and" : [
                    {
                      "$gte" : [
                        "$BornTime",
                        ISODate("2015-08-11T21:00:00Z")
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "$lte" : [
                        "$BornTime",
                        ISODate("2015-08-11T21:30:00Z")
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
              },
              3,
              "noSlot"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

}

So each "slot number" is returned depending on where the current "BornTime" value falls into each slot. If it does not belong in any slot, then the "noSlot" value is returned.

So with a lttle help from nested [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) you get all of your results in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

```
var slotes = ;// init from req.body

var bortTimeSlotes = [];

    for(var i=0; i<slotes.length; i++){
        var slot =  { "bornTime" : { "$lt" : slotes[i].startdate, "$gt": slotes[i].endDate } };
        bortTimeSlotes.push(slot);
    }

db.childrenModel.find(
    {
        "$and" : [ bortTimeSlotes  ]
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks. the time slots may vary at times, ther can be 7 or 1. Is there a way to do this, if i pass an array. Sorry, I'm still noob in this.

Comment: How to determine in which time slots have data.